# How to print labels of individual bars of barchart on clicking them in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, onclick, label, bar-chart

I am not able to print labels while clicking on bars

I have tried it using get_label() method but labels are not printing on clicking bars

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def main():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    labels = ['Apple', 'Mango', 'Orange']
    size=[20, 40, 60]
    y_pos=np.arange(len(labels))    
    wedges = ax.bar(y_pos,size)
    plt.xticks(y_pos,labels)
    plt.xlabel("Fruits")
    plt.ylabel("Count")    
    plt.title("Fruits Count")
    make_picker(fig,wedges)
    plt.show()

def make_picker(fig, wedges):
    def onclick(event):
        wedge= event.artist
        label = wedge.get_label()
        print(label)
    for wedge in wedges:
        wedge.set_picker(True)
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onclick)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Expected result : When I click on any bar then corresponding label of that bar should get printed. RESULTS OBTAINED: when I am clicking on bar then *nolegend* is getting printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `Artist.get_label()`, then you need to set the label of the artists *somewhere*, using `Artist.set_label(label)`:

```
def main():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    labels = ['Apple', 'Mango', 'Orange']
    size=[20, 40, 60]
    y_pos=np.arange(len(labels))
    wedges = ax.bar(y_pos,size)
    # Assign a label to each of the artist to be retrieved later
    for w,l in zip(wedges, labels):
        w.set_label(l)
    plt.xticks(y_pos,labels)
    plt.xlabel("Fruits")
    plt.ylabel("Count")
    plt.title("Fruits Count")
    make_picker(fig,wedges)
    plt.show()
```